# $firebaseArray inside of a $firebaseObject?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Using AngularFire, if I am using a `$firebaseObject` where one of the properties of the object is an array, is it possible to represent that array as a `$firebaseArray` so that I can access the API and use functions such as `$add`?

Answer (score 1):

"yes" but probably not how you're thinking. You can just get to that childnode if you're going to want it.

```
var parent = $firebaseObject(firebase.database().ref().child('parent'));
var children = $firebaseArray(firebase.database().ref().child('parent').child('children'));
```

If you need to wait for parent to load, hook into the `$loaded()`

```
$firebaseObject(firebase.database().ref().child('parent')).$loaded().then(function(parent){
    if(parent.children){
        parent.children = $firebaseArray(firebase.database().ref().child('parent').child('children'));
    }
});
```